# Adding a child node to XML in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

In a Flex application, I'm have an xml object that I'm binding to a tree control.  I'm able to add a child node to the xml but when I try to add a child to the child node it doesn't appear on the tree control

```
tree =  <node label="Root">
                        <node label="Category 1"/>
                        <node label="Category2"/>
                        <node label="Category3"/>
                        <node label="Category 4">
                            <node label="SubCategory4.1"/>
                            <node label="SubCategory4.2"/>
                        </node>
                    </node>;                    
            var someNode:XMLNode = new XMLNode(9, 'Category5');         
            var aSubNode:XMLNode = new XMLNode(9, 'SubCategory5.1');
            someNode.appendChild(aSubNode);                                 
            tree.appendChild(someNode);
```

So Category5 appears on the tree control but SubCategory5.1 does not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using flex, use AS3.  XMLNode is AS2.  In short, try this:

```
tree = <node label="Root">
           <node label="Category 1"/>
           <node label="Category2"/>
           <node label="Category3"/>
           <node label="Category 4">
               <node label="SubCategory4.1"/>
               <node label="SubCategory4.2"/>
           </node>
       </node>;
var someNode:XML = <node label="Category5"/>;
var aSubNode:XML = <node label="SubCategory5.1"/>;
someNode.appendChild(aSubNode);
tree.appendChild(someNode);
```